# Is there a way to disable buttons on main form via a user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to disable some buttons on my main form using a user control that is in a panel on main window. This code doesn't work I think because of inheritance.

```
MainWindow mW = new MainWindow();
mW.button1.Enabled = false;
mW.button2.Enabled = false;
mW.button3.Enabled = false;
mW.button4.Enabled = false;
mW.button5.Enabled = false;
mW.button6.Enabled = false;
mW.button7.Enabled = false;
```

Please advice some other method.

Comment: Where is written this code? You should use the instance of the MainWindow which is shown and NOT create a new one.

Comment: This code is written in a button in user control

Comment: You're creating an instance of MainWindow and then disabling the buttons for that instance. It will surely do the intended work. If you call Show() function on it the buttons will be disabled

Comment: If that control is on the form you want to affect, how can creating a new form help? You need to access the existing form. You could call the `FindForm` method of the user control or, if it has been placed directly on the form, access it via the `Parent` property. That would not be best practice though. The proper way to do this would be for the user control to raise an event that the form can handle and then the form can disable its own `Buttons`.

Comment: @kamakadze so this code is written in the `MainWindow`'s `Button`'s click event handler? If it is so then just replace `mW.button...` with `this.button...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `this.FindForm()` to get a reference to the form containing the user control, cast that reference back to `MainForm`, and control the buttons on your `MainForm` (assuming they are `internal` or `public`).
However, that would probably be the wrong thing to do.

A better approach would be to create an event in your user control, have the main form listed to that event, and in the event handler change whatever you want in the main form.
This way, your user control is not bound to a specific form, and you can reuse it in other forms as well.

You can inherit the `EventArgs` class to send specific data with the event - in this case, a boolean value indicating if the buttons should be enabled or disabled:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(bool enable)
    {
        Enable = enable;
    }

    public bool Enable {get;}
}
```

And then, in your user control:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SomethingHappened;

// to raise it:
SomethingHappend?.Invoke();
```

In the main form, you subscribe to the event:

```
MyUserControl.SomethingHappened += MyUserControl_SomethingHappened;
```

And in the event handler you enable / disable the buttons:

```
private void MyUserControl_SomethingHappened(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = e.Enable;
    button2.Enabled = e.Enable;
    ...
    button7.Enabled = e.Enable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will definitely try this as this is the best practice but for the mean time I am short on time so I used the Control method like this.

`Control[] Co = this.TopLevelControl.Controls.Find("pInfo", true);
Co[0].Enabled = false;`

Thanks everyone for the help.